# infdig Infinite $digest Loop in table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am implementing a table with CSS which is changed in each row but one **td** of table contains another **table**. I have implemented it like this :

HTML code :

```
 <table width="100%" class="table">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 11%">Location</th>

                <th><div>                   
                <table class="table" style="table-layout: fixed;width: 100%; margin-bottom: 0px;">
                <tr>

                <th style="width: 12%">Col1</th>
                <th style="width: 12%">Col2</th>
                <th style="width: 12%">Col3</th>
                <th style="width: 11%">Col4</th>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
            </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody style="overflow-y: auto; max-height: 200px;">

        <tr data-ng-repeat="Loc in LocationList">

                <td style="width: 11%;">{{Loc.locationName}}</td>

                <td><div>
                <table class="table" style="table-layout: fixed;width: 100%;margin-bottom: 0px;"">
                <tr data-ng-repeat="a in Loc.locations">

                <td data-ng-class="(checkEvenOrOdd()) ? 'odd' : 'even'" style="width: 12%;">{{a.subLocName}}</td>

                <td data-ng-class="(!evenOrOdd) ? 'odd' : 'even'" style="width: 12%;">{{a.typeName}}</td>

                <td data-ng-class="(!evenOrOdd) ? 'odd' : 'even'" style="width: 12%;">                          
                        <span style="color: red;" data-ng-show="{{a.unassigned}}">{{a.prfName}}</span>
                        <span data-ng-show="!{{a.unassigned}}">{{a.prfName}}</span>
                </td>
      </tr>
                </table>
                </div>
                </td>
            </tr>

            </tbody>
```

JS code:

```
$scope.evenOrOdd = true;

        $scope.checkEvenOrOdd = function()
        {
           if($scope.evenOrOdd==true)
         {
            $scope.evenOrOdd=false;
            return !$scope.evenOrOdd;
         }
          else
         {
           $scope.evenOrOdd=true;
           return !$scope.evenOrOdd;
         }

        };
```

This code gives me correct output but after clicking one any link on the page it gives me this error

```
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [["(checkEvenOrOdd()) ? 'odd' : 'even';
```

I searched for this error and tried some code changes but not able to solve it. Please note it is not just to check even or odd row. There is some ordering in rows. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

I would instead use `ng-class-even/ng-class-odd` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClassEven:

```
<table class="table" style="table-layout: fixed;width: 100%;margin-bottom: 0px;"">
                <tr data-ng-repeat="a in Loc.locations">

                <td data-ng-class-even="'even'" data-ng-class-odd="'odd'" style="width: 12%;">{{a.subLocName}}</td>

                <td data-ng-class-even="'even'" data-ng-class-odd="'odd'" style="width: 12%;">{{a.typeName}}</td>

                <td data-ng-class-even="'even'" data-ng-class-odd="'odd'" style="width: 12%;">                          
                        <span style="color: red;" data-ng-show="{{a.unassigned}}">{{a.prfName}}</span>
                        <span data-ng-show="!{{a.unassigned}}">{{a.prfName}}</span>
                </td>
      </tr>
                </table>
```

Or alternatively it can be done using css but this won't work in IE8:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```